# Janela datetimepicker fora deslocada

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, bootstrap-3, datepicker

Estou com um problema quanto a posição em que a janela do datetimepicker aparece, como na imagem abaixo ela aparece à direta e um pouco distante do campo de origem, gostaria que ela ficasse centralizada e abaixo do campo e próxima também.
Agradeço quem puder me ajudar.
Seguem a imagem e o código que estou usando.

[image: janela deslocada]

```js
$('.data_formato').datetimepicker({
weekStart: 1,
todayBtn: 1,
autoclose: 1,
todayHighlight: 1,
startView: 2,
forceParse: 0,
showMeridian: 1,
language: "pt-BR",
//startDate: '+0d'
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<!--Campo Previsão-->
<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-4">
<label for="previsao" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >
<br>Previsão:</label>
<div class="col-sm-11">
<div class='input-group col-lg-5 date data_formato' data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy HH:ii:ss">
<input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="00/00/0000 00:00:00"/>
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--Fim Campo Previsão-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

$(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                widgetPositioning: {
                    horizontal: 'left',
                    vertical: 'top'
                }
            });
        });